# ASP.NET Core + React - SPA is shown when trying to reach api

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application with React+Redux, using Visual Studio 2019 default project template.
The SPA should run when the user navigates to "/" but it shows up whatever I type in the url, including api endpoints with GET verb.

I've added some configuration in the startup, but it's basically the same, and I haven't  moved anything around:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseWebSockets();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

I have an API inside a controller `LinkToUtilsController` (which is decorated with the attribute `[Route("api/[controller]/")]`) whose purpose is to get a link id and redirects to an external resource (or returns an HTTP error).
The endpoint is `http://localhost/api/linktoutils/redirect?linkId=STEP`, but when I open it from the browser, it shows the ReactJS application (which don't even use routing and will never need it).
Strange thing is that it works if then I force reload the page with CTRL+F5 or in incognito.

This happens either from localhost or production.

Comment: _“which works... but only when on ReactJS application I reload the page with CTRL+F5”_ – This is not clear to me. How are you calling your API?

Comment: From the browser. That specific API is a proxy for a link, it gets an ID and redirects the user. I'll try to rephrase that.

Comment: But how? Is this an AJAX request? Is this a link that you generate with a `href` the user clicks on? Is this a button where you send the user to when they click it?

Comment: On click, the app opens a popup window with that URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I stumbled upon a very similar problem to this. I was developing an ASP.NET Core / ReactJS app using VS2019. When developing, everything worked fine with regards to calling the .NET API backend, but when I deployed to production, navigating to the routes of the API calls in the browser caused the React app to be returned and not the API calls.  If I did a hard reload on these pages in the browser, the API responses would be returned and not the React application.

I resolved this issue by removing a call to registerServiceWorker that was included in the React / JS portion of the project by default.  I was able to check for the presence of the service work by using the browser developer tools (F12) and selecting the Application tab.

Comment: I don't have any service worker setup (and yet, it generates a service-worker.js file)

Comment: @IIARROWS I would try to see if you can see if a service worker is running on your site by using the  debug console (F12) when you're in your browser. Perhaps your problem is different, but my problem was pretty much identical. Right down to the hard reload causing the API calls to return correctly.

Comment: Yes, a service worker was running, I added a line of code to unregister it and my problem seems resolved. I also failed to mention the issue wasn't happening in incognito, probably because it remembered a very old service worker (I removed it a couple of week before publishing this question).