# Can't access a dotnet API due to an SPA Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I'm serving a React app through dotnet's `UseStaticFiles`. this allows the front-end to communicate with the front-end by simply fetching to localhost. Now I would like to deploy a 2nd front-end outside this close-loop, problem is, I can't access the underlying backend since all requests are being handled by its front-end.

Say I would like to access `/users`, then the front-end would try to match that route, if it doesn't find it, then it will display a 404 error page.

I tried mapping the controller routes under `api` like so.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

BUt I am still unable to access the API under the `/api` base path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947758/asp-net-core-react-spa-is-shown-when-trying-to-reach-api